# Give App Service enough permissions to link SSL certificate from Key Vault

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager, azure-keyvault, azure-bicep

I have a Bicep template where I create an `App Service` in which I need to link a SSL certificate that exists in Key Vault (both in same resource group).

The Key Vault has Azure RBAC enabled.

I use the following to Bicep template to link the SSL certificate from Key Vault to the App Service:

```
resource certEncryption 'Microsoft.Web/certificates@2018-02-01' = {
  name: '${resourcePrefix}-cert-encryption'
  location: location
  properties: {
    keyVaultId: resourceId('myResourceGroup', 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults', keyVaultName)
    keyVaultSecretName: '${resourcePrefix}-cert-encryption'
    serverFarmId: hostingPlan.id
    password: 'SecretPassword'
  }
  dependsOn: [
    webApi
  ]
}
```

But it fails with the following message:

> The service does not have access to '/subscriptions/3449f-xxxx/resourcegroups/rgabptrialt/providers/microsoft.keyvault/vaults/my-test-vault' Key Vault. Please make sure that you have granted necessary permissions to the service to perform the request operation.

This isn't really telling a lot...

What permission do I need to grant **exactly**? And to what? And where and how do I even grant these permissions?

Do I have to create a Managed Identity and link that in my App Service? And what Permissions/Roles do I need exactly? Or do I need to do something else to make this work?

I couldn't really find any good info on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

> Give App Service enough permissions to link SSL certificate from Key Vault:

I've imported a *self-signed certificate* (.pfx)  in `keyvault -> secrets` to authenticate.

[image]

**To resolve,**

> The service does not have access to '/subscriptions/3449f-xxxx/resourcegroups/rgabptrialt/providers/microsoft.keyvault/vaults/my-test-vault' Key Vault. Please make sure that you have granted necessary permissions to the service to perform the request operation.

***I tried in my environment by referring few steps from this*** [article](https://dotnetthoughts.net/managing-ssl-certificate-with-azure-keyvault/#:%7E:text=In%20the%20Web%20Application,%20select%20TLS/SSL%20settings%20and,bind%20the%20SSL%20certificate%20to%20the%20custom%20domains.) ***detailed by @Anuraj and modified accordingly to achieve the expected results.***

**Step-1**: ***Setting up a Key Vault access policy:***

1. Create a `key vault` from the portal and Goto `Access Policies`.

[image]

2. Now creating an access policy to link the `ssl certificate` by configuring a template as per your requirement.

I've selected `key,secret & certificate management` to enable the permissions as shown:

[image]

3. Search for the "*Name/objectID/AppID*" for the respective service principal as keyvault has RBAC enabled.

   **Note:** Register an app under `AzureAD -> App registrations` if  needed.

[image]

4. Review all the permissions and create an access policy:

[image]

**Step-2:** Under `App Service -> Web Application -> Certificates`, I've added the keyvault certificate  (  *self-signed certificate* (.pfx)  in `keyvault -> secrets`).

1.
[image]

2.
[image]

3.

[image]

***Bind the SSL certificate by adding TLS/SSL settings and importing the key vault certificate when it has been added to key vault (.pfx).***

[image]

**Note:** *Make sure the certificate is in* `.pfx` *format to avoid any conflicts.*

*And I ran below script and deployment got succeeded without any permission blockers*.

```bash
resource  certEncryption  'Microsoft.Web/certificates@2018-02-01' = {
name: 'xcc-cert-encryption'
location: 'EastUS'
properties: {
keyVaultId: '/subscriptions/<subscriptionID>/resourceGroups/xxxxRG/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/xxxxxkeyvaults'
keyVaultSecretName: 'jahnss'
password: 'xxxxx' //Certificate protected password
extensionResourceId: '/subscriptions/<subscriptionID>/resourceGroups/xxxxRG/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/xxxxxappserviceplan'
}
}
```

***Output:***

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your effort. But this is about Access Policies. I'm talking about RBAC permissions (Role Based Access Control), which works differently.

Comment: As of now, Key vault certificate only supports key vault access policy but not RBAC. Thats why I have provided you the relevant solution. You can [refer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1101781/what-permission-is-needed-exactly-to-allow-an-app.html) here.

Comment: No it doesn't. It's me in that forum you are referring to. You should read my last reply in there more carefully. You see how I ended up saying: "And all of this is working using the RBAC model... ". So it does work. All I needed to know were what permissions I had to use. Once I figured that out it all worked.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the App Service resource provider doesn't have access to your key vault. To use a key vault for a certificate deployment, you must authorize read access for the resource provider to the key vault.

[image]

So for your scenario RBAC doesn't work currently, I will advise you to use **Key Vault Access Policy**.

See here for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate?tabs=apex#authorize-app-service-to-read-from-the-vault

Answer (score -1):

I think yes first you need to give permission in key vault

`Ensure that the service principal has all the permissions. The only thing that worked for me though is adding the service principal 24681998-555f-4570-a559-2fced2d7e841 which shows up as Microsoft.Azure.WebSites. You can add this through the portal, by adding an access policy for Microsoft.Azure.WebSites or through arm with the GUID.`

I added the following principal to the Key Vault access policies: Microsoft Azure App Service (object id: your object id). Permission to get secrets is enough.

By performing similar the steps mentioned in the below answer

[How to access key vault from azure app service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73516925/how-to-get-connection-string-for-database-from-appsettings-json-for-local-and-az/73961444?noredirect=1#comment131066846_73961444)

Please let me know if you have any doubts or question. Even if you are facing any issues.